# Extract a list to Excel

Tags: 2013, list, excel

How do I extract a SharePoint 2013 list to Excel meeting this requirements?

- I cannot use SharePoint Designer.
- I do not want to use the export option as I want to be able to call this outside of SharePoint.
- I have no experience with scripting.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the list afterward? How do you want your system/users to initiate the export (an external application, a provider hosted app, from the list's view pages?) I understand your limitations, but what you're trying to accomplish is unclear.

Comment: If you **export** from SharePoint you end up with an Excel file which has no relation with SharePoint. So what does "*I want to be able to call this outside of SharePoint*" mean?

Comment: Getting the list into excel outside of sharepoint is the goal.  My hope was to configure an auto export of the list, however my companies system does not allow scripts to do that.  My next thought was to just try to extract the data from outside of sharepoint into excel.  We just want to create graphs from the information.  The list will be used by people entering "timesheet" type of information.  I appreciate the support!

Comment: @DannyEngelman nope you're wrong. When exported, it just exports a query file which executes a query to SharePoint to get the data. Running it when you have no access to the sharepoint site is useless.

Comment: @Akhoy you're technically right, but then you can just save the data itself (think copy/paste values or remove external connections) and it is completely detached -- so I'm unsure why the built in export functionality couldn't meet this need, just try sending them the exported excel sheet!

Comment: And by outside of SharePoint do you mean you'll have no access to the Sharepoint environment?

Comment: As I said, I have no scripting experience and do not know what they are capable of and how they process.  I do have site collection admin privledges to my teams particular site.  I guess I do not understand what you are saying, my apologies, but thanks for the time.

Comment: Thank you Akhoy.  We were hoping to auto generate the export.

Comment: As @John-M said, export to excel should work that way. Or you can also use PowerQuery in excel to connect to the sharepoint list which is similar to export to excel.

Comment: Thank you Akhoy, how is that accomplished with PowerQuery in Excel.

Comment: Added the answer.

Comment: I am using Excel 2007.  I did try to connect via Excel using "from Web" and received the this error message. "You may be trying to access this site from a secured browser on the server. Please enable scripts and reload this page."

Comment: I used Access to connect directly to the list.  Set up a daily export from Access to Excel.  I believe this will work.  Thanks to all who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

I used Access to connect directly to the list. Set up a daily export from Access to Excel. I believe this will work. Thanks to all who tried to help.